# performance penalty for having column as TEXT?

Tags: mysql, database-design, text, varchar

I have a content management system in which a user can dynamically create an html form. I have all the tables setup for that. But there's one thing that troubles me and that is, the text size for the entered values.

Some forms have textareas and some textareas contain quite an amount of data. But there are also just simple textfields on the form, which contain just a few characters of data.

My database table for saving the values kind of looks like this:

**form_values**

```
id | form_id | fk_element_id | value
```

So in this case the `value` column will hold the entered data for a specific field type. So in the case of a textfield this will only be a few characters. But in the case of a textarea, this can be alot of data.

That means the `value` column must be at least of type `TEXT`. Eventhough most types will not exceed 255 characters `(MAX VARCHAR)`.

Now i'm not sure if this is the right approach. Will this give a performance penalty when i query the table? Do i have to save the textarea data in another table..? Or something like that?

Or can i simply change the `value` column to a `TEXT` type without any problems..?

Comment: Personally I would use the type of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for that as you can store up to 2GB of text in a SQL Server cluster. I dont know about MySQL but i know that in SQL Server you cannot do a `LIKE` search on `TEXT` column

Comment: @Qpirate Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have a NVARCHAR type. Just a `VARCHAR` type, or a `TEXT` when you want to store more than 255 characters. And indeed, the querying on a `TEXT` column is another issue i have. I don't think i need to do a `LIKE` anytime soon. But i'd like to tackle as many problems i can in advance.

Comment: VARCHAR maximum length is 255 prior to MySQL 5.0.3 , from MySQL 5.0.3 onwards the maximum length is 65535 , which is the maximun row size, so that maximum value is shared among all fields in the row.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: @Nelson Wow, thanks. I didn't know that. That actually solves my problem then. I'll just use a `VARCHAR` then. It looks like a `VARCHAR(3000)` (3000 characters) utf8-encoded column, will take up to 9000 bytes. Where the max is 65535 bytes if i understand it right. I'll probably need to double that to make sure it can hold more than enough characters for my purpose. Could you please post it as an answer so i can accept it later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VARCHAR maximum length is **255** prior to **MySQL 5.0.3** , from **MySQL 5.0.3** onwards the maximum length is **65535** , which is the maximun row size, so that maximum value is shared among all fields in the row.

See [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)